# Performance is crucially slow and very lagging

Tags: 11.10, performance

Linux Ubuntu 3.0.0-12-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 14:50:42 UTC 2011 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux

Hardware config is AMD Athlon Processor and 500 GB harddisk with 2GB RAM

this is my system config. and after upgrading to 11.10 using Update manager, i really find hard time in performance overall in using applications. The mouse is moving poor and the system is giving me so many lack in my work. The compiz s up and running. Even my chrome application is taking long time and my graphics is very very poor.. I never felt the same evr with my lovely ubuntu.. And one crucial information is, its taking 20 seconds to open my gedit :(

Please help me

Comment: Try Unity 2D next time when you are on Login screen. Also good tip is first to try Live CD and then install if satisfied, afterall 11.10 comes with Gnome 3

Comment: Please try running System Monitor and reporting any processes that are using a lot of CPU.

Comment: Same problem... on Intel 4 G 500mb .. ATI - Just did the up date and its running way slower then before. Also many of the setting that I had where reset to the defaut setup. Lots of lag with nothing running... When the system info is running I can see a huge change when I move my mouse.. system is resting at 25% and when I move the mouse it jumps to over 48%... thats huge.... Something in the update has really changed for the bad.. also didn't that it removed all my settings to the default.
(Im about to remove unbuntu and go back to windows xp as it was faster then this.)

Answer (score 2):

Check your graphics card. nVidia cards have been choking on this update, but the recent driver alleviates most of the issues with slow performance. Upgrade the driver, restart, and everything should be working up to speed.

If this doesn't work post additional details and switch to Ubuntu Classic in the mean time so you can still get work done.